# cancel previous request live search reactjs

Tags: react-redux, axios, debouncing

I need to cancel the previous request with live search axios request- I am using throttle-debounce to make requests, but I am having issues when existing word is erased and new value is updated - results are being shown for previous word in some cases, I think I need to cancel all previous requests for same requestID, read through articles but none of them work for my usecase. any help is appreciated here is my code.

reducer:

```
switch (action.type) {
case GETTING_DATA:
  return {
    ...state,
    results: action.payload,
  };
case SEARCH_DATA:
  return {
    ...state,
    Results: action.payload,
  };



export function getSearch(value) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: GETTING_DATA,
    });
    const arg = {
      search: value,
    };
    apiGet('abc', arg).then(response => 
     getResults(dispatch, response));
  };
}
const getResults = (dispatch, response) => {
  dispatch({
    type: SEARCH_DATA,
    payload: response.data,
  });
};
```

service:

```
export const apiGet = async (path = '', args = {}) => {
  const endpoint = "/aaa/aaa/aaa";
  try {
    return axios.get(endpoint, getConfig());
  } catch (e) {
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

Pass `value` as a payload to the `GETTING_DATA` action. This will store the latest requested value in the state.

Then, in `getResults` send that same value to the reducer along with the response data. Inside the reducer, check whether the value passed from `getResults` is the same as the one stored in the state via `GETTING_DATA`.

If so, this data is coming in response to the latest request, so you want to store it in the state. Otherwise, you can just ignore it.

In other words:

**Action:**

```
switch (action.type) {
case GETTING_DATA:
  return {
    ...state,
    lastRequestTime: action.payload,
  };
case SEARCH_DATA:
  if (action.payload.lastRequestTime === state.lastRequestTime) {
    return {
      ...state,
      Results: action.payload.response,
    };
  } else {
    return state
  }
```

**Action:**

```
export function getSearch(value) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const lastRequestTime = Date.now()
    dispatch({
      type: GETTING_DATA, 
      payload: lastRequestTime
    });
    const arg = {
      search: value,
    };
    apiGet('abc', arg).then(response => 
     getResults(dispatch, { response, lastRequestTime }));
  };
}
const getResults = (dispatch, response) => {
  dispatch({
    type: SEARCH_DATA,
    payload: response.data,
  });
};
```

Comment: Did not understand how to use it with my code especially how to trigger cancel method inside the action - should it come from the component..?

Comment: Try the following: pass `value` as a payload to the `GETTING_DATA` action. This will store the latest requested value in the state. 

Then in `getResults` send that same value to the reducer along with the response data, and inside the reducer check whether the `value` passed from `getResults` is the same as the one stored in the state via `GETTING_DATA`. If not, you can disregard the data. Otherwise, this is the data you want to store in the state.

Comment: @jacekhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/1967872/jacek-lampart - Thanks for your response - i tried passing in the value in GETTING_DATA - how do i get the value from state(present state) - I have updated my question with my reducer code - would you mind updating it as per what you are saying

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967872/jacek-lampart..? could you please update my code with what you are saying - tried but could not get state and not sure how to do the comparison in reducer

Answer (score 0):

You can create such a small helper wrapper and use it anywhere where you need to cancel the previous request:

```js
// ../services.js

function createApi(baseURL) {
  const axiosInst = axios.create({
    baseURL,
  });
  // here you can set default headers:
  axiosInst.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  // return the function with closure variable to use for canceling
  return (type = 'get') => {
    let call = null;
    return (url, data, config) => {
      if (call) {
        call.cancel('Only one request allowed!');
      }
      call = axios.CancelToken.source();
      const extConf = {
        cancelToken: call.token,
        ...config,
      };
      switch (type) {
        case 'request':
          return api[type](extConf);

        case 'get':
        case 'delete':
        case 'head':
          return api[type](url, extConf);

        default:
          return api[type](url, data, extConf);
      }
    };
  };
}

export const baseApi = createApi('http://localhost:5000/api/')
```

And then use it anywhere like this:

```js
import baseApi from '../servises.js';

const fetchItemsService = baseApi('post');

//...
componentDidMount() {
  fetchItemsService('/items').then(() => {});
}
//...
```